# PHP Client C# server

Tags: c#, php

How i can do something like PHP client who will sending commands to C# console.application server

For example : When i'am clicking on button in php client, this button have to call

```
process.start("@cmd.exe");
```

Any sources?
 Sorry for my English.

Comment: You should implement a `http server` or something like `web sockets`.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Can you give some example code on PHP?